# Increase value in DB every X days

Tags: php, sql

I have some value in the DB, and I want to manipulate it on a schedule

I know that there is a way to manipulate things on a schedule, but I don't know how to do it.

I need it for 2 reasons:

1. I need to increase value in DB every day by X. For example the value is 100 and I need to increase it by 4 everyday - 104, 108, 112, etc.
2. I want to send email to all users in DB everyday at a specific time.

Comment: These sound like jobs.  You can look into how your database handles jobs.

Comment: Don't understand, can you please explain or send me some reference to learn from it?

Comment: The answer to this question will likely be RDBMS-specific. Please add specific tag(s) for your question (e.g. MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon has mentioned, you're probably looking for a SQL Job. If you are in Sql-Server you can find this under "SQL Server Agent" and create a new job. You can set that job to execute a stored procedure daily. Then in that stored procedure you can increment whatever value in whatever table you want to update.

Docs:[*Sql-Server-Agent*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent/)

[MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)